# Issue with pagination in Datatables implementation

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am having a small issue with pagination. When implementing the "four_button" type, the table displays correctly (with correct pagination buttons) however clicking on any of the pagination buttons (Next, Previous, etc...) will throw an error of "fnCallbackDraw is not a function". Inspecting it further in Firebug, i see that fnCallbackDraw is a div (div.dataTables_paginate). Looking within the code, I do not see where this value is being assigned??!!
To make matters more interesting the other pagination implementation of "full_numbers" works correctly.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used the datatable plugin, there are only two options for pagination namely "full_numbers" and "two_button". I don't think "four_button" type exists even in the latest plugin as I have been using version "1.8.2". Try using either of "full_numbers" or "two_button" types.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks Praveen but there is a way to create a four button pagination in the framework itself (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination). I tried following the process that has been outlined, also another team has implemented the same code; nevertheless I get the above error. It is very baffling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fnCallbackDraw. It is fnDrawCallback. Without seeing your DT initialization code, I'm guessing it's just a syntax error. ;-)

If I'm wrong, post back with a copy of your initialization object and we'll see if there's anything else going on there.